# Tensorflow: using argmax to slice a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor with shape `tf.shape(t1) = [1, 1000, 400]` and I obtain the indices of the maxima on the 3rd dimension using `max_ind = tf.argmax(t1, axis=-1)` which has shape `[1, 1000]`. Now I have a second tensor that has the same shape as `t1`: `tf.shape(t2) = [1, 1000, 400]`.

I want to use the maxima indices from `t1` to slice `t2` so the output has the form

```
[1, 1000]
```

A more visual description: The resulting tensor should be like the result of `tf.reduce_max(t2, axis=-1)` but with the location of the maxima in `t1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this through [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), although it is not really straightforward. For example,

```
shape = t1.shape.as_list()
xy_ind = np.stack(np.mgrid[:shape[0], :shape[1]], axis=-1)
gather_ind = tf.concat([xy_ind, max_ind[..., None]], axis=-1)
sliced_t2 = tf.gather_nd(t2, gather_ind)
```

If on the other hand the shape of your input is unknown as graph construction time, you could use

```
shape = tf.shape(t1)
xy_ind = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(tf.range(shape[0]), tf.range(shape[1]),
                              indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
```

and the remainder is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific reason you are using np.mgrid and not tf.meshgrid? Won't this impact performance on GPU?

Comment: No, the `np.array` will be passed only once to the graph and stored there as a constant. Use `tf.meshgrid` if the size of your tensors are unknown during graph construction.

Comment: if anyone is wondering, with pure TF it works like this: `xy_ind = tf.transpose(tf.meshgrid(tf.range(tf.shape(t1)[0]), tf.range(tf.shape(t1)[1]), [2, 1, 0])`

Comment: @NicoJ I think it would be simpler to use `tf.stack` in that case -- just like in the `np` case. I add this to the solution.

Comment: This will actually not work because `tf.meshgrid` outputs a different shape than `np.mgrid` so you would still need to do the transpose if I am not mistaken

Comment: `xy_ind = np.stack(np.mgrid[:1, :1000], axis=-1)
print(xy_ind.shape)` outputs `[1, 1000, 2]` while `xy_ind = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(tf.range(1), tf.range(1000)), axis=-1)
s = tf.shape(xy_ind)
print(s.eval())` outputs `[1000, 1, 2]`

Comment: @NicoJ Oh yeah you are right, `meshgrid` inverts the x and y order. I will fix that in my solution (still using `stack` to avoid a transpose).

Comment: Just realizing that `meshgrid` has an `indexing` argument just like in numpy. Will use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.reshape` to avoid generating index grid. For me this is more easy to understand (especially if you are familiar with `reshape` logic). The basic idea is to unfold the tensor to a 2D matrix.

```
#generate a 3D tensor as example
a  = tf.random.uniform(shape=(8,9,10), minval=0, maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32)

ix = tf.argmax(a, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int64)
#indices for unfolded a: 
ix2 = tf.stack((tf.range(8*9, dtype=tf.int64), tf.reshape(ix, (8*9,))), axis=1)

#get values based on ix2
b = tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(tf.reshape(a, (8*9, -1)), ix2), (8,9))

#verify
tf.reduce_all(tf.reduce_max(a, -1) == b)
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```